# My turtle program in python acts like it has been clicked

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()

pen = turtle.Turtle()

def star():

    pen.forward(100); 

turtle.onscreenclick(star())

window.mainloop()
```

I am very new to turtle,and python itself, I am just using some of the documentation that I found on the python website, but when I run this program it runs my function star without the screen even being clicked. The end goal of this program would be for me to click then it would run the function, then if I clicked again the screen would clear and the function would be run again.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass reference to start function into onscreenclick, and make start to accept two arguments:

```
def star(x,y):

    pen.forward(100);

turtle.onscreenclick(star)
```

Comment: I actually tried that before, but it said "takes two two arguments (given 0)"

Comment: @Centrum123 really? in my python x and y are passed. Maybe have different version than you. If so, just remove x, y from start arguments.

Comment: Does that mean go back to def star():    Because that was what I have in my original which is not working correctly.

Comment: @Centrum123 in your code you pass `star()` which is result of start function, not its reference. Did you change to reference as I wrote?

Comment: Oh! I didn't even notice that I passed it as start(). Thank you so much, and it worked when I put (x,y) in.

Comment: @Centrum123. Glad i could help. If you happy with the anwser, accepting it would be good.